# Diagonal Lyapunov equation with rank 1

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

Given the discrete-time Lyapunov equation (1):

$$
A^T P A - P = bb^T 
$$

such that $P$ shall be diagonal and positive definite and $b$ is a column vector. How to characterize $A$ and $b$, where there are diagonal solutions $P \succ 0$? More precisely,

$$
S = \{A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}, b \in \mathbb{R}^{n}  \mid \exists \textrm{ diagonal } P \succ 0 \textrm{ for } (1) \}
$$

How to characterize $S$?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Can you please be more specific? About the characterization?

Comment: Do you have access to Mathematica? This question can be solved via *quantifier elimination* and boils down to finding the parameters for which a linear program is feasible. The question needs further editing, too. In a Lyapunov equation, $A$ and $b$ are given and the goal is to find $P \succ 0$. Here, the goal is to find the sets in which $A$ and $b$ live such that the Lyapunov equation is solvable. By the way, set $S$ should include the set in which $b$ lives, too.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Thanks for the comments. Unfortunately, I don't have access to Mathematica. I try to see whether there might be another way to get it. I agree with your comments, however, I feel that the question reflects well your statement. Maybe add 'Solvability of' in the title?

Comment: If you make $P = \mbox{diag} (x_1, \dots, x_n)$, you should be able to write the linear program in ${\rm x} \geq 0_n$.

Comment: You can get a necessary condition via Gaussian elimination.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo How? That is not at all evident to me. Note that $A\otimes A - I$ need not be invertible.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Assuming the matrices are $n \times n$, don't we have $\binom{n+1}{2}$ linear equations in $x_1, \dots, x_n \geq 0$? I am not vectorizing.

Comment: Yes, that seems the correct number of equations, but you also need to eliminate the nonlinear $b$ variables to get a condition on $A$ only. And in any case it is not that easy to get a condition via Gaussian elimination, since you need 'branches' to check if pivots are zeros or not.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni Why would the condition be on $A$ only? Essentially, one has a linear system with non-negativity constraints. Using Gaussian elimination, one should be able to conclude if the linear system is even feasible. If it is, then one can use quantifier elimination. If it is not, then the linear program is also infeasible. Using quantifier elimination in, say, Mathematica, may produce a quantifier-free formula large enough to fill some 100 A4 pages, or more.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo Hmm, looks like I was looking at an earlier edit of the question when the condition was asked on $A$, not on the pair $(A, b)$. OK, I take back the comment on eliminating $b$.

Answer (score 2):

It seems hopeless to me. The considered equation

$A^TPA-P=bb^T$ can be rewritten $\phi(P)=bb^T$, where $\phi=(A^T\otimes A^T-I_{n^2})$ -if we stack the matrices row by row into vectors-.

If $spectrum(A)=(\lambda_i)_i$, then $spectrum(\phi)=(\lambda_i\lambda_j-1)_{i,j}$. Thus, in general , there is a unique solution

$P=(\phi)^{-1}(bb^T)$. On the other hand, since if $P$ is a solution, then $P^T$ too, $\phi^{-1}$ is an automorphism of the symmetric matrices.

Condition 1. The obtained symmetric $P$ is diagonal; there are $n(n-1)/2$ equations (dependent or not) linking the entries of $A=[a_{i,j}],b$.
For example, when $n=2$ and $b=[88,-72]^T$, the condition is

[image]

When $n=3$, writing conditions takes up a lot of space!

Condition 2. $P>0$. That certainly works if the $(|\lambda_i|)_i$ are $>1$.

Comment: Is P missing in the definition of $\phi$?

Comment: No, $\phi$ is an endomorphism of $M_n$. cf. Kronecker product.

Answer (score 1):

I make a different attempt to answer the question. $A,b \in S$ if there exists $c$ and $d$ such that

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
A & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A^T & c^T \\ b^T & d
\end{bmatrix}
= 
\begin{bmatrix}
P & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$

This is equivalent to 
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
P^{-1/2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
A & b \\ c & d
\end{bmatrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
P^{1/2} & 0 \\ 0 & 1
\end{bmatrix}
$$
being orthonormal. Thus $A$ is a submatrix of an (diagonally conjugated) orthonormal matrix. By Theorem 2.1 in [Fiedler,1996](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0024379508003595) $A$ has at least $n-1$ singular values equal to 1 and the remaining one is less than 1. Diagonal conjugation may change this of course.